# Rails - can't render related model attributes in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

Here my models:

```
class Train < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :train_lines
end

class TrainLine < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :train
end
```

My controller:

```
# controllers/train_lines_controller.rb
class TrainLinesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @train_lines = TrainLine.all
  end
end
```

And here my views:

```
# views/train_lines/index.html
<%=  render @train_lines %>

# views/train_lines/_train_line.html.erb
<p><%= train_line.train.id %></p>
```

I get `undefined method`id' for nil:NilClass` error

If I run Rails console I can successfully call:

```
$ tl = TrainLine.first
$ tl.train.id
$ 6028
```

### EDIT

It seems it renders something, and for some reason it breaks. I get the following in the log:

> Rendered collection of train_lines/_train_line.html.erb [6197 times]
>   (5875.4ms)   Rendered train_lines/index.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (5992.4ms) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in
>   6008ms (ActiveRecord: 1165.4ms)
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
>       1:
>
> <%= train_line.train.id %>

Any clue?

Comment: Try ```@train_line.train.id```.

Comment: Can't find declaration for @train_line

Comment: You'll have to declare it in your controller.

Comment: In my controller, in index action I defined @train_lines = TrainLine.all

Comment: Then try using ```@train_lines``` instead of train_lines. Or iterate over ```@train_lines``` to get a specific train_line.

Comment: where? I already use @train_lines!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147217/discussion-between-hashrocket-and-davideghz).

Comment: Is that the only one `@train_lines` defined?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma yes, as far as I know (I don't get any `multiple implementations` warning)

Comment: Can you see a `Rendered collection of ...` in the server's log?

Comment: Yes I do! Actually I think it encounter an empty or corrupted line while iterating over the collection and it breaks. I edited my Q with mroe details

Comment: Are you sure that trainline is the first one, the one you see on the console, what does `<p><%= train_line.train.inspect %></p>` print?

Comment: Are you sure that trainline is the first one, the one you see on the console, what does `<p><%= train_line.train.inspect %></p>` print?

Comment: I inspected the DB and I found out an empty line at the end of the table. It was causing the lookup on the foreign key to return null ;( wasted 2 hours of my life LOL

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting the DB  I found out an empty line at the end of the `train_lines` table. It was causing the lookup on the foreign key `train_id` to return null. Calling `id` on null stopped the render and caused the page not to load.